# How do I fix this? CSS '::Before' is not working in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use ::before in CSS, but it doesn't work. I need it to create a hover effect. But I had to learn this, but I just can't seem to use it properly. I don't know why; I tried every tutorial on YouTube, but it just doesn't want to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>

       <center>

           <a href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Get+rickrolled"><button id = "Btn" class = "Btn" >Rickroll</button></a>

           <style>

               .Btn::Before {

                   Content: '';
                   Position: Absolute;

                   Border-Width: 5px;
                   Border-Color: Cyan;
                   Width: 150px;
                   Height: 50px;

                   Font-Size: 30px;
                   Font: Comic;
                   Align-Items: Center;

                   Margin-Top: 50px;

                   Z-Index: -1;

                   transition: 0.6s;
               }
           </style>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. `<a>` elements may not contain `<button>` elements.

Comment: And the CSS comes before the HTML

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you expect to see? You haven't given the psedu-element any content, or colour, or border, or outline, or anything else that would create a visible effect … and you haven't told us what visible effect you expect.

Comment: i put css before the body and after <head> yet it still doesnt work

Comment: I gave it a size, border color and font size, yet nothing happened

Comment: @SxS — Setting the colour of a border you don't have won't do anything.

Comment: What does that mean? What? "you dont you have wont do anything"

Comment: @SxS — If I don't have a border. And then I make the border *which doesn't exist* pink. Then I won't see anything pink because the border **doesn't exist**.

Comment: Shouldn't `<center>` have an end tag (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        Button:hover {

            background-color: green;
            Content: '';
            Position: Absolute;

            Border-Width: 5px;
            Border-Color: Cyan;
            Width: 150px;
            Height: 50px;

            Font-Size: 30px;
            Font: Comic;
            Align-Items: Center;

            Margin-Top: 50px;

            Z-Index: -1;

            transition: 0.6s;
        }

   </style>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Prakhar+Doneria" target="black"><button>Rickroll</button></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., *what* did you change? *Why* did you change it? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72125838/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -2):

First put `<style> </style>` inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: While that is an error, it isn't the cause of (or even a contributing factor to)  the problem

Comment: I did, wdym? ... ... ... ...

Comment: Why did you provide two answers? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72125645/edit) (change) your posts.